# Sharepoint Webpart Custom toolpart

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, web-parts

I added a property to my webpart main.cs

```
   public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()

        {
            ToolPart[] toolparts = new ToolPart[4];
            WebPartToolPart wptp = new WebPartToolPart();
            CustomPropertyToolPart custom = new CustomPropertyToolPart();

            CalendarToolPart datumswahl = new CalendarToolPart("Coutdown Datum Wahl");

            toolparts[0] = datumswahl;
            toolparts[1] = custom;
            toolparts[2] = wptp;

            return toolparts;
        }
```

I then built this class toolpartClass.cs

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;  
using Microsoft.SharePoint;  
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;  
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;  

namespace Custom_Toolpart.toolparttest  
{    
    class CalendarToolPart : ToolPart     
{  
        public Calendar datumWahl = null;  
        private void CalendarToolPart_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            datumWahl = new Calendar();  
            datumWahl.ID = "datumWahl";  

            SyncChanges();  
        }  

        public CalendarToolPart(string strTitle)
        {
            this.Title = strTitle;
            this.Init += new EventHandler(CalendarToolPart_Init);
        }

        public override void ApplyChanges()
        {
            //base.ApplyChanges();
            EnsureChildControls();  
        }

        public override void SyncChanges()
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
            Controls.Add(datumWahl);
            this.ChildControlsCreated = true;   //?
        }
    }
```

My problem is, that I can't use/call the calendar out of the toolpartClass.cs

What I want to do is, that the selected date is given to the "toolpartUserControl.ascx.cs" (the code behind) where I want to use the date and display a result in the toolpart.ascx

It is no problem to use the "normal" added webpart properties in the toolpartUserControl.ascx.cs, like here

```
namespace Custom_Toolpart.toolparttest  

{  

    public partial class toolparttestUserControl : UserControl  

    {  

        public toolparttest WebPart { get; set; }  

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnPreRender(e);

            DateTime datumAuswahl1 = DateTime.Parse(Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM") + "/" + Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd") + "/" + Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy"));
            DateTime datumJetzt = DateTime.Now;

            TimeSpan mySpan = new TimeSpan(-24, 0, 0);
            datumJetzt = datumJetzt.Add(mySpan);


            TimeSpan laufzeit = datumAuswahl1 - datumJetzt;
            string ausgabeLaufzeit = string.Format("{0}", laufzeit.Days);

            int i = Convert.ToInt32(ausgabeLaufzeit);
            if (i >= 2)
            {
                lbl_6.Text = "Tage";
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                lbl_6.Text = "Tag";
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                lbl_6.Text = "Tage";
                lbl_hide.Visible = true;
                lbl_1.Visible = false;
                lbl_2.Visible = false;
                lbl_3.Visible = false;
                lbl_6.Visible = false;
            }

            lbl_2.Text = ausgabeLaufzeit;


            if (this.WebPart != null && this.WebPart.CountDown_Text != null)
            {
                lbl_1.Text = this.WebPart.CountDown_Text.ToString();
            }

            if (this.WebPart != null && this.WebPart.Event_Text != null)
            {
                lbl_3.Text = this.WebPart.Event_Text.ToString();
            }

            if (this.WebPart != null && this.WebPart.Header_Text != null)
            {
                lbl_4.Text = this.WebPart.Header_Text.ToString();
            }

            if (this.WebPart != null && this.WebPart.Main_Text != null)
            {
                lbl_5.Text = this.WebPart.Main_Text.ToString();
            }

            if (this.WebPart != null && this.WebPart.Link_Edit != null)
            {
                hyplnk_1.NavigateUrl = this.WebPart.Link_Edit.ToString();
            }

            if (this.WebPart != null && this.WebPart.Ablauf_Text != null)
            {
                lbl_hide.Text = this.WebPart.Ablauf_Text.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I send the selected date to the toolpartUserControl.ascx.cs class?

Comment: Your issue is that the date needs to be persisted across postbacks into some kind of persistable store.  The most common approach is to define a persistent property in the WebPart, decorate WebBrowsable(false), Personalizable(..).  After that access the instance of the webpart from the ToolPart using ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart in ApplyChanges.

Comment: @Roman 

Thx for your suply, the persistence thing was my idea too, but dindt know how to solve. The persistent property is no problem, im now trying to give access, to the instance, in the toolpart.

Comment: @Roman

For a third hint, i would be thankful :)

Comment: your main goal is to hold on to the value across post-backs. you could use ViewState btw as well, if that value is only valuable during Toolpane being open.  In Asp.Net, the entire control hierarchy is recreated on every request, so you have to get your previous state from somewhere.